# Search all files for a specific error type in IntelliJ / PhpSotrm

Tags: php, intellij-idea, constructor

We recently upgraded on of our projects to PHP7, which doesn't allow the following:

```
class SomeTestClass {

  /**
   * This is the constructor
   */
  public function SomeTestClass (){
    //Whatever
  }
}
```

The constructor should be renamed to `__construct` instead of the class-name. PhpStorm correctly indicates this as "Old style constructor usage". Can I search all files of my project for this specific error type?

Comment: FYI: There's a syntax error in your code: Class should be lowercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an inspection for this: **PHP → Code Style → Old style constructor**.  You can then use the menu **Code → Inspect code** to find them all.

[image: Code inspections]

Comment: This searches for all errors / warnings and even typos. While still helpfull, ideally it would only show errors of the specific error type needed

Comment: The inspections are grouped by type (and optionally by severity and directory), so you can easily find the single one you're interested in. However it will of course take longer to run all inspections and you might end up finding more problems than you wished for ;)

Answer (score 2):

Expansion on jlh's answer: I created a custom Inspection profile with only the one inspection needed:

[image]

This can then be chosen in the inspect code dialog:

[image]

If you run the inspection on the project now, it only shows this specific error type.